# I need a better way of counting words in a text area?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to count the words in a textarea, basically just `string.split(' ');`

This method is seriously hopeless. I cannot even work out what it is doing on some of the counts. For example I can have no text in there at all, and it gives me a positive number.

I'm not sure either if it's the `string.split(' ')`, method, or something with the `<textarea>`, or some incompatibility of the two.

Here is my code:

```
    <body>

    <textarea rows="14" cols="50" id="text">

    </textarea>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <button onclick="show()">Analyze</button>

    <div id="results"> 

    </div>


<script> 

    var a1 = [];     
    var words = 0; 

    function show() 
    {

        // GET WORDS 
        var s = document.getElementById("text").value; 
        a1 = s.split(' '); 
        words = a1.length; 


        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = words;

       }

    </script>

    </body>
```

Comment: When you encounter a problem, come up with a list of inputs and the corresponding list of outputs, then figure out what the list of outputs _should_ be, and compare the difference. If you still don't know what's wrong, show us those things.

Comment: I'm not much with javascript, but I think it might be better to use split(" ") rather than split(' ')... perhaps it's different?

Comment: Splitting on space won't take end of line characters into consideration.  Perhaps do a replace of those first, then split on space.

Comment: @markg The two are identical in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newlines you have there still count! The spaces between the spaces also become empty strings.

I’d use a regular expression, which you can easily alter based on what you consider a word:

```
var WORD = /[a-zA-Z\d'’-]+/g;
⋮
var words = s.match(WORD).length;
```

Comment: fantastic. i really need to learn how to use regular expressions i think.

Answer (score 0):

Turn everything that's not a number, letter, underscore, or apostrophe into a space; then count the runs of things between the spaces as "words".

```
var numWords = myTextArea.replace(/[^\w'’]+/g,' ').split(/\s+/).length;
```