# How to get matched words into an array?

Tags: javascript

This is a follow up question to this one [I need a better way of counting words in a text area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109278/i-need-a-better-way-of-counting-words-in-a-text-area)

I'm counting words in a `<textarea>`, regular expression. This only counts the words though, what I need to do is not only have a count of the words, but an array of the words, which I could express using `array.length`. I need an actual list of the words, not just a count of them.

My thought was to put the regular expression checker inside a for loop of something?

Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <textarea rows="14" cols="50" id="text"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="show()">Analyze</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script>
        function show() {
            var words;
            /// GET WORDS
            var s = document.getElementById("text").value;
            var word = /[a-zA-Z\d'’-]+/g;
            var words = s.match(word).length;
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = words;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `match` already returns an array...

Comment: See the answer below, the regular expression is messy fixed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete example:

```
<body>

<textarea rows="14" cols="50" id="text"></textarea>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<button onclick="show()">Analyze</button>

<div id="results"></div>
<script> 


  function show() {
    var words,
      s = document.getElementById("text").value,
      word = /[a-zA-Z\d'’-]+/g,
      // If no matches, returns null, fallback to empty array
      words = s.match(word)||[],
      wordCount = words.length; 
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = words; 
  }


</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to change this line: `var words = s.match(word).length;` to `var words = s.match(word);`

Now you have words as the array of words... The idea is that `s.match(word)` itself is an array... Adding a `.length` there only returns the length of this array.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is not correct try this

```
 var words = "this is a word list";
 var wordm = /(\w+)/g;
 var beer = words.match(wordm); 
 console.log (beer); // prints the array
 console.log (beer.length); // prints 5
```

The '\w+' matches any words and the '()' groups them and the g repeats it.  They then get placed in an array.

Comment: I removed the case insensitive switch as you do not need it for the case of '\w'. I did test this code and results are as specified.